# AlarmManager isn't fired from Service

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

So i would like to make an Alarm repeating (for demonstrate purposes) every 60 seconds. 
I give a signal to the BroadcastReceiver which then starts a NotificationService. 
Due my Android (4.4/Kitkat) isn't liking the `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60* 1000, pendingIntent);` method i've tried to set the Alarm from the MainActivity and then set the Alarm again from inside the Notification Service (so that the alarm is started everytime the AlarmManager is fired). My Sample is below:

My **MainActivity** where alarmMethod is called in onCreate:

```
public void alarmMethod(){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
     calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);

      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Vertreter.this, 0, myIntent,0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**MyReceiver:**

```
package de.madstar.asg_erfurtvertretungsplan;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);

   context.startService(service1);


}   
}
```

**NotificationService:**

```
package de.madstar.asg_erfurtvertretungsplan;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NotifyService extends Service {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent2;
final Context context = this;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Toast.makeText(context, "This is a PopUp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Call AlarmManager again
    alarmMethod();
   }


public void alarmMethod(){

      Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
      pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent2,0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

      alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 1000, pendingIntent2);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm 2 started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.madstar.asg_erfurtvertretungsplan"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.madstar.asg_erfurtvertretungsplan.Vertreter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
             android:enabled="true" />
    <service android:name=".NotifyService"
             android:enabled="true" />


    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

So my problem is that the Alarm from the NotifyService is called (which i can see at the Toast "Alarm 2 started" ) but it isn't fired after the **60** seconds ... 
Maybe important to say that this App has to run on  **Android 2.3 to 4.4**

My problem would also be solved if someone could tell me how i set up a working `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` for Android 2.3 till Android 4.4.

Thanks in advance - MadTracki

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it to work right with this constellation:

```
public void alarmMethod(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36); 
          final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
          PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
              am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
              //Toast.makeText(context, "<4.4 Alarm start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
              setAlarmFromKitkat(am, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
          }
    }

@TargetApi(19)
    private void setAlarmFromKitkat(AlarmManager am, long ms, PendingIntent pi){
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ms, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "4.4 Alarm start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```